# Create a SelectBox using Form Helper in CakePHP3

Tags: forms, cakephp, helper

I am trying to make a combo box for an edit page.

```
echo $this->Form->select('status', 
                        ['empty' => 'Select Status'], 
                        ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']
                    );
```

Here I want to add 2 things :

```
$options = array('0' => 'Inactive',
                 '1' => 'Active',
                );
```

and selected value. suppose that is $status;

I tried with different options but sometime it do not add classes and sometime it shows options in  tag

It will be great if somebody give clue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?= $this->Form->input('status', [
        'type' => 'select', 
        'options' => ['0' => __('Inactive') , '1' => __('Active')], 
        'empty' => __('Select Status'),
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'required' => true, 'label' => __('Type')
    ]) 
?>
```